# Testing with Jasmine component and service

Tags: angular, jasmine

I was wondering how I can test following code in Angular?

```
create() {
        this.loading = true;
        const email = this.email.value.originurl;

        this.emailService.create(data).subscribe((id) => {
          this.setID(id);
          this.info();
          this.loading = false;
        });
      }
```

Answer (score 0):

this is just one way, there are multiple things to test depending on what bug you want to catch early

First Refactor code, on this line, Extract Method

```
          const email = getEmail();
```

this is the new Method for that, so that we can spyOn this later

```
       getEmail():string {
       return this.email.value.originurl;
      }
```

Then create a mock service in the .SPEC file

```
    let  mockEmailService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['create']);
```

Then in the testbed, notice the provider value here

```
      TestBed.configureTestingModule({
  declarations:[Component1, Component2],
  imports: [HttpClientTestingModule,SomeModule],

  providers: [
    {provide: EmailService, useValue: mockEmailService}
  ]
  ...

  ....
    });
  }));
```

Then on the Unit test

```
   it('should call email service create on create() at least once', () => {

  //Arrange

  spyOn(component,'getEmail').and.returnValue('mockemail@emailer.com');
  mockEmailService.create.and.callThrough();

  //Act
  component.create();
  //Assert
  expect(mockEmailService.create).toHaveBeenCalledTimes(1);


});
```

this is just a sample, again just to show you what you can do at FIRST. Feel free to change this one and get familiar with mocking, spies and Testbed

Comment: Ok many thanks. Can I also use multiple spyOn if I for example have more function like getEmail. Can I use spyOn always for setting test data like yours or is it also possible to mock getEMail? Could you please provide an example? It would help me very much.

Comment: It depends. If you want to mock a service/class and access the methods/properties within it:
    mockSimpleLookupBaseService = jasmine.createSpyObj(['method1', 'method2', 'method3']);   If you want mutiple spyOn, you can do this multiple times... spyOn(component, 'displayNotification').and.callFake(function(){ console.log('fake display notification') });    If my answer has helped you ,pLease  ACCEPT my answer, there's a check under the voting arrows